# On primitive Pythagorean triplets with same greatest term

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For the purpose of this question, I'll define a *primitive Pythagorean triplet* as a triplet of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ such that

1. $a$ is odd;
2. $b$ is even;
3. $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$;
4. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

The set of all primitive Pythagorean triplets (PPTs) can be partitioned according to the value of $c$, the greatest term in the triplet.  Let $[c]$ denote the class in this partition corresponding to $c$.

*Empirically*, I find that

1. the sizes of the classes are always powers of 2;
2. the lowest $c$ for a given class size is always divisible by 5.

Are these statements true in general?  Where can I find proofs or counterexamples?

---

Below are a few examples of the findings described above:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|l|r|} \hline
 \left|[c]\right| &
\begin{array}{l}
(a, b) \\
\end{array}
& c  \\  \hline
2^0 &
\begin{array}{l}
(3, 4) \\
\end{array}
& 5  \\  \hline
2^1 &
\begin{array}{l}
(63,16) \\
(33,56)
\end{array}
& 65 \\  \hline
2^2 &
\begin{array}{l}
(1073, 264) \\
(943, 576) \\
(817, 744) \\
(47, 1104)
\end{array}
& 1105 \\  \hline
2^3 &
\begin{array}{l}
(32037,716) \\
(31323,6764) \\
(27813,15916) \\
(23067,22244) \\
(21093,24124) \\
(17253,27004) \\
(8283,30956) \\
(2277,31964) 
\end{array}
& 32045 \\  \hline
2^4 &
\begin{array}{l}
(1177473,139136) \\
(1164447,223304) \\
(1129887,359384) \\
(1112703,409504) \\
(1074273,501736) \\
(1027743,591224) \\
(1015137,612616) \\
(927903,738104) \\
(782463,890816) \\
(661377,984064) \\
(540417,1055344) \\
(463263,1091416) \\
(448767,1097456) \\
(303873,1146064) \\
(279807,1152176) \\
(81567,1182856)
\end{array}
& 1185665 \\  \hline
\end{array}$$

For each $i\in\{0,...,4\}$, the table gives the triplets in $[c]$ for the lowest value of $c$ such that $\left|[c]\right| = 2^i$.

For example, $1105$ is the lowest $c$ such that $\left|[c]\right| = 2^2 = 4$, and the PPTs in $[1105]$ are

$$
\begin{array}{l}
(1073, 264, 1105) \\
(943, 576, 1105) \\
(817, 744, 1105) \\
(47, 1104, 1105)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: These results follow from understanding factorization in the ring of Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: Great question! Really interesting topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from [Fermat's theorem on the sum of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).  $65$ is the first number that is the product of two primes equivalent to $1 \bmod 4$.  $32045$ is the first number that is the product of four of those.  All of these numbers will have $5$ as a factor, and all after $5$ will have $13$ as a factor, etc. If the prime factors of form $1 \bmod 4$ are distinct and the factors of form $3 \bmod 4$ are only squares you can then use the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) to generate $2^n$ solutions where $n$ is the number of primes of form $1 \bmod 4$ Your requirement that the triple be primitive forces that all prime factors to be one one side or the other, which maintains the $2^n$ behavior.  You can contrast the situation with $c^2=5^6=15625$ with solutions $(35,120,125), (44,11,125), (75,100,125)$ but only one is primitive.  Thanks to kjo for pointing out that two of these are not primitive.

Comment: Neither (35, 120, 125) nor (75, 100, 125) is primitive.

Comment: @kjo:  good point.  I think one can turn this into a proof in favor of $2^n$, which takes chasing primes through the identity.  Thinking on it.